# Django and wordpress simultanous logout

Tags: javascript, python, django, wordpress

I have this project in which user simultaneously login into Django as well as Wordpress accounts.

To achieve Simultanous logout, I used Javascript to delete the authentication cookie of Wordpress and thus automatically logging out the user. This works fine as long as user clicks on "logout" button. On clicking logout a Javascript function is called and wordpress cookie is deleted and thus making user logged out of Wordpress and user is logged out of Django by using normal Django functionality.

Now the problem occurs when user directly type the logout url "localhost:8000/logout" in address bar, this directly send request to Django server and without involving any JavaScript to delete the Wordpress cookie.

How to achieve Wordpress logout in this situation when user directly types the logout url of Django?

Note:- Wordpress and Django server are running on same host with different port.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with an one more browser,
For an example:

In an main browser you will log a Django project, an private browser (crtl+shift+p in an Firefox) you can use word press project.

Comment: I don't see how this solves my problem.
I have tested my code, It works fine in private window and other browsers.
The problem occurs only when the user types in logout url directly, that leaves wordpress logged in but django logged out. I can not run my javascript when user directly use url.

Comment: You can change the session variable name for any one